Programmatically copying text from the Linux server to the Window's client's clipboard?
I'm connecting from a Windows client, using Windows Terminal, to a Linux server. I would like a program that runs on that Linux server to put a piece of text in the clipboard of the Windows client. Is that possible?
Edit: I need to do this without writing text to the console.

Yes, using the OSC 52 (ESC ] 52) sequence.

Command: \e]52
Parameter 1: c (copy)
Parameter 2: Base64-encoded text
Terminator: either \e\\ or \a

text="Hello world!"
b64=$(printf '%s' "$text" | base64 -w0)
printf '\e]52;c;%s\a' "$b64"

tmux needs this to be prefixed by another "pass-through" sequence \ePtmux;, see this post.
tmux setw -g allow-passthrough on
printf '\ePtmux;\e]52;c;%s\e\\' "$b64"


I need to accomplish this without writing text to the console.

Unfortunately, the console is literally your only interface to the client. Everything is done by writing hidden sequences to the console.

To repeat that key word, hidden - @RamRachum - Your program that runs on the Linux end is what would generate that OSC code. It will not show up on the screen, but is simply an "instruction" to the terminal.  You may need to provide more information in your question about your use-case, such as what type of application it is, what control you have over it, etc.
